# Can we use reserved keyword as method name in OC?

Tags: objective-c, keyword, reactive-cocoa

I found a reserved keyword list for OC at [here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/objective-c-reserved-keywords/43).

However, in ReactiveCocoa's code, I found an example

```
@interface RACReturnSignal : RACSignal
    + (RACSignal *)return:(id)value;
@end
```

Here it uses `return` as a method name.

Is it OK to use this kind of code style?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, that method is named `return:`. not `return`.

Comment: This is also a non-technical question that is opinion-based.  (Is it OK...)